# VMWare to Azure - multiple VMDK files, how to handle?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, vmware, vhd

this might seem like a remarkably simple question, but I want to be sure before I proceed and I was struggling to find any information regarding this.

I am currently in the process of transferring an existing VMWare environment to Windows Azure. I have been given three different VMDK files, one for each hard drive of a server, and am aware that I need to convert these to VHD for image upload in Azure.

My question is whether I need to make these VMDK files into one VHD image or if I can upload multiple VHD images and work with them in the portal. I have seen that it is possible to convert multiple VMDK files into a solitary VMDK file, but I am unsure if this would be appropriate.

This is my first exposure to this work, so apologies if this seems like pure basics!

Comment: Your question is offtopic as it's not a practical programming question.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise this was off-topic. I will remember for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about VMWare-specifics but if these VMDK files can be broken down into 1 system disk + multiple data disks, then you can upload all of them into Azure once converted into VHDs.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm now uploading the VHDs to the container so hopefully I should have no issues.